# Why does the entire profile section have the hand cursor?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, user-experience

On the profile tab on any user, there is a small "Summary" of the profile showing their avatar, reputation and their badges. It seems a little counter-intuitive for all the parts to have the hand cursor because it feels like it should do something.

For example, since the badge summary areas have the hand cursor, I would intuitively think that clicking them could take me to the badges section of the user. However, nothing happens. The only part of this area that actually does something is the avatar which takes you to the Profile tab of the user (You can see this a the end of the gif).

Here is a gif of what I mean:

[image]

> Chrome 75.0.3770.100 on main only

Comment: Dang, it’s actually only on main… repro on Firefox Nightly 69.0a1.

Comment: Have the same effect on the main page (FF 56 and Chrome 75). Like ivarni said, doesn't happen on meta, though

Comment: The entire `.avatar-card` div has `cursor` set to `pointer` on main, but not here on meta. Browser shouldn't really make any difference.

Comment: Reproduced in FF 67.0.4 as well.

Comment: If the behaviour is not expected, shouldn't it be a bug then?-

Comment: Oh i didn’t meant that. This isn’t unusual or distrupts the normal working of the site. Its just a UX improvement. More of a feature request

Comment: @weegee: This is clearly [a reproducible problem on the site that \[...\] is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info) A low-priority bug is still a bug.

Comment: @weegee: That _is_ the programming error. The `cursor: pointer` style is [supposed to be used](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#valdef-cursor-pointer) on clickable link-like elements, which the user card clearly isn't. (In fact, the style seems to be leaking from the Developer Story style sheet into all [cards](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/cards) on all user pages because its selector isn't selective enough. And I'm not even sure if it's actually used for anything on the Dev Story tabs, or if it's just leftover clutter from some earlier design iteration.)

Comment: Now this is a bug. @IlmariKaronen

Answer (score 14):

The bug is caused by the following style in the [developer story style sheet](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Shared/DevStory/story.css), which is leaking into the main user profile page on SO:

```css
.s-card {
    position: relative;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: box-shadow 600ms cubic-bezier(.165, .84, .44, 1)
}
```

and overriding the default [card](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/cards) styling from [stacks.css](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css):

```css
.s-card {
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #d6d9dc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #FFF
}
```

A simple fix (assuming that the pointer cursor on all cards is, in fact, desirable in the developer story tab) would be to change the selector for that style (and any others that might be having the same issue) from just `.s-card` to `.developer-story .s-card`.